# Coffeescript and problems with encodings of Ruby 1.9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, coffeescript, ruby-1.9

A basic task: evaluate field's value and show warning if results are not satisfying. The actual code doesn't matter, since it works perfectly until I actually change sample warning's test to the one, which should actually be there, which throws this accursed error at me:

```
Error: Encoding::UndefinedConversionError: U+0417 from UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1
```

In any other case I would've used i18n or magic comment, but neither seem to work here, since apparently you can't mix ruby into .coffee file. Is there any way to avoid this without resorting to putting unnecessary javascript into views?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **can** use ruby in coffeescript assets. Just rename the file to `.js.erb.coffee` and use good old `<%= ruby_code %>`.

Comment: Ah, you're right, my mistake. But the problem still stands: while assists pipeline indeed takes information from i18n it does so before final compilation. Yet you actually helped me to discover the way: file needs to be renamed to `.js.erb.coffee` for proper sequence of compilations. Please, edit your answer to reflect this and I'll accept it.

Comment: Not yet actually. If you don't add `.js` in the beginning file will be compiled into html :)